# What is mean by "result shall be round ties to even" ? How to convert integer to float ? and result shall be round ties to even?

Tags: c

I am going to write a code to convert integer value into float value. but condition is result ties to even.

```
 void main()
 {
   uint8 value1;
   float32 returnVal; 
  returnVal = (float32 )value1;
 }
```

Is it correct way to conversion?

Comment: Huh? In the `uint8` range, a conversion to `float` is lossless. Unless your `float32` is pathologically funky (7 bit or less mantissa?) there is no complication here.

Comment: The cast is redundant (and, some people would say, therefore wrong).

Comment: I suggest you provide a working example of the issue.   I am guessing your assignment is to perform some kind of bankers rounding, but the details are not clear.

Comment: "round to even" basically means `13.5 ==> 14`, `14.5 ==> 14`.

Comment: Hi @EvilTeach Pls find the snapshot of the document..

Comment: @Tejas: Which, with respect, is about as useful as a colander on a sinking ship. Have you looked at `round`?

Comment: The spec says you get a float value as input and shall return a rounded integer value. Why do you convert integer to float instead the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

[“Ties to even”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) is a rounding strategy where floating point numbers exact in the middle between two integer numbers (“ties”) are rounded towards the even number:

- 0.5 → 0
- 1.5 → 2
- 2.5 → 2

etc.

In particular, this is the recommended, standardised rounding strategy for [IEEE floating point numbers standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

However, none of that is relevant in the code you’ve posted: No rounding is performed when converting an integral type number to a floating point type number as long as that integer can be exactly represented by a floating point number of the target type, which is the case here.

Comment: I agree, but if I convert 123 to float  then ans will be 123.00 ? So how “Ties to even”  works here?

Comment: @Tejas Is this question not answered by the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: as per  IEE754 format I need base and exponent to convert the value . Also it convert float value decimal value but my query is for integer to float value.. also my second doubt is 123.00 if I round it ans will be the same. So is it correct?

Comment: @Eric (I’m assuming you mean “ties to even” instead of “round-to-nearest” because I make no assertion regarding round-to-nearest vs direct rounding, except that the latter is conventionally denoted by more specific terms?) It literally says that in the linked Wikipedia document: “this is the default for binary floating point and the recommended default for decimal.” By contrast, “ties away from zero” isn’t supposed to be used for binary floating point numbers. — I haven’t checked the original standards document to check whether Wikipedia is correct.